# How to disable double tap event on mobile for radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I am creating a form with radio buttons. It works fine on the computer but fails on the mobile because I have to double-tap to select a radio button. Users will get confused.

How do I disable the double-tap requirement? I've checked a few other answers but they're all using different code and I'm not sure how to apply it in my situation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
function myFunction() {
   
        if(document.getElementById('monthly').checked) {
            document.getElementById('myLink').href = "https://www.rageheart.co/beast-monthly";
        }
        if(document.getElementById('yearly').checked) {
            document.getElementById('myLink').href = "https://www.rageheart.co/beast-yearly";
        }
        if(document.getElementById('onemonth').checked) {
            document.getElementById('myLink').href = "https://www.rageheart.co/beast-1-month";
        }

    }
```

```html
<form><div class="monthly-box"><label for="monthly" class="container">
  <div class="monthly-header">Most Popular</div>
  <div class="monthly-body">
  <div class="monthly-input"><input type="radio" id="monthly" name="payment" value="monthly" checked="checked"><span class="checkmark-monthly-yearly"></span></div>
  <div class="monthly-text">
    <h2>Monthly Subscription - $79 USD <span style="color:#929292;font-weight: normal;"><s>$99</s></span></h2>
    <ul>
      <li>60 recorded audio lessons + live class on Zoom</li>
      <li>1-on-1 welcome call with the founder</li>
      <li>7-Day Free Trial + 90-Day Money Back Guarantee</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </label>
  </div>
  
    <div class="yearly-box"><label for="yearly" class="container">
  <div class="yearly-header">Best Value</div>
  <div class="yearly-body">
  <div class="yearly-input"><input type="radio" id="yearly" name="payment" value="yearly">  <span class="checkmark-monthly-yearly"></span></div>
  <div class="yearly-text">
    <h2>Yearly Subscription - $474 USD <span style="color:#929292;font-weight: normal;"><s>$1,188</s></span></h2>
    <ul>
      <li>60 recorded audio lessons + live class on Zoom</li>
      <li>1-on-1 welcome call with the founder</li>
      <li>14-Day Free Trial + 90-Day Money Back Guarantee</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </label>
  </div>
  
    <div class="onemonth-box"><label for="onemonth" class="container">
  <div class="onemonth-header"></div>
  <div class="onemonth-body">
  <div class="onemonth-input"><input type="radio" id="onemonth" name="payment" value="onemonth"><span class="checkmark-onemonth"></span></div>
  <div class="onemonth-text">
    <h2>Try One Month - $99 USD</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
  </label>
  </div>

</form>

<a href="" onclick='myFunction()' id="myLink">Checkout &#8594;</a>
```

Comment: Can you explain by what you mean "double tap" on mobile devices?

Comment: I have to tap the screen twice to select a radio button. If I tap once, nothing happens or changes. It's only when I tap twice within a second or so that a radio button selects. So my understanding is that there's something in the javascript that's requiring 2 taps rather than just 1.

Comment: Do you have this same problem with all websites when you are viewing on a mobile device and radio buttons?

Comment: No. I just checked another website with radio buttons and it works with one tap. So there's something in my script/html (I'm guessing) that's requiring 2 taps instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

the labels need to be associated to the radio button

````js
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
labels.forEach(function (label) {
    label.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Trigger the click on the associated radio button
        var radioButton = this.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
        radioButton.click();
        // Call your function after the radio button is clicked
        myFunction();
    });
});```
````

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Didn't work for me. I added your code at the end of the existing script (inside the <script> tags). Still required a double tap to select a radio button... and the redirect when someone clicks "Checkout" stopped working. The page just refreshed instead of going to the checkout page. Did I set it up wrong? Or do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

i have one more idea actually

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var labels = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
    labels.forEach(function (label) {
        label.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Find the associated radio button
            var radioButton = this.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
            
            // Manually set the checked property
            radioButton.checked = true;

            // Call your function after the radio button is manually checked
            myFunction();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Tried this one too. Tried it on its own as well as with the first script you posted. Neither worked.